# Concatenate tuple sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

We work on a google map where each user is show with markers.

We have a input field, where the visitor can search for an user. We want to use an autocompletion plugin (coolautosugest) for autocomplete the name of user.

The plugin need a SQL request to get the name. There an example of the table where the user name are saved :

```
field_id | user_id | value
1        | 2       | Doe
35       | 2       | John
1        | 14      | Obama
35       | 14      | Barack
```

Where field_id 1 is the last name, and the field_id 35 is the first name

What we need for the autocompletion plugin:

```
user_id | name
2       | John Doe
14      | Barack Obama
```

The SQL request tha we have for now is :

```
SELECT user_id, value FROM wp_sokatira_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id=35 OR field_id=1
```

And the result is :

```
user_id | value
2       | Doe
2       | John
14      | Obama
14      | Barack
```

Does someone better than us with SQL have a solution for our problem/challenge ?

Thank you,

Benjamin Dubé (and three other classmates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY field_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ') as name
FROM wp_sokatira_bp_xprofile_data 
WHERE field_id=35 OR field_id=1
GROUP BY user_id
```

A suggestion from my side:

You can use `IN` in where clause:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY field_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ') as name
FROM wp_sokatira_bp_xprofile_data 
WHERE field_id IN (35,1)
GROUP BY user_id
```

**EDIT:**

Use `LIKE` as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY field_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ') as name
FROM wp_sokatira_bp_xprofile_data 
WHERE field_id IN (35,1) AND ColName LIKE %$test%
GROUP BY user_id
```

Parameterize the variable `$test`.

Comment: If you have the time, I have a sub-question.

Now with the result, we need to add a : LIKE '%test%' where 'test' is generated dynamicly by the plugin.

Thank You in advance for your help!

Comment: It is working if we do the LIKE on a column that have a "real" name like "user_id", but I try with "name", but it's an alias for the column, so it's doesn't work. I try with "GROUP_CONCAT" as the column name, and "GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY field_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ')" but with no sucess.

There is a way ? If not, don't waste your time, we will find an another way to do the autocompletion.

Antoher time, thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminDubé: It is a pleasure helping you, my friend. BTW, you cannot filter by the alias name. Try it with the actual column name `value`.

Comment: I had also try with value, and it's work, but it's the original, not concatenate, value that is show :s

Comment: Try `HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY field_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ') LIKE %name%` after `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Also I don't know why you have separated first and last names but since that wasn't a question, here is a simple example of query

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY field_id DESC SEPARATOR ' ') AS value
FROM `wp_sokatira_bp_xprofile_data`
GROUP BY user_id
```